# Dynamically populate checkboxlist in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, in the database view I have the USERs list with their descriptions and what Type of USers are they.
For Eg. Some USer Type are : DE, Some others are : admin etc etc etc.

So now I want to populate the CheckBoxList on PageLoad.

- If CheckBoxList1 = "DE" then all the UsersNames of Type "DE" will the displayed.
- If CheckBoxList2 = "admin" then all the UsersNames of Type "admin" will the displayed.
- If CheckBoxList3 = "Coord" then all the UsersNames of Type "Coord" will the displayed.
- etc etc

then I will select whether I should give permission to the whole group or only to a particular user.

I couldn't Bind the Checkboxlist and populate the UsersName according to the UserType.

Comment: This is kludgy, Can may yr question more clear wat excatly hv u achieved so far in that ?

Comment: So far I have achieved to populate all the users name inthe Checkboxlist, without any segregation according to the user type.

 private void bindUser()
{User use = new User();
 use.OrderBy = "Order By User_Name";
 ChkUser.DataSource = use.GetUserDS();
 ChkUser.DataTextField = "User_Name";
 ChkUser.DataValueField= "User_Id";
 ChkUser.DataBind();}
 
Now I want to display the users name segregating according to the users Type.

Comment: public DataSet GetUserDS()
        {
            DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter oDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            
 string Query = "select User_Id,User_Name,Company_Id,UserRole_Id,UserRole_Name from v_mst_User " + WhereClause + OrderBy;
string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
oDs = ebma.DataAccessLayer.SQLHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConnString, CommandType.Text, Query);
     return oDs;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You could try `use.OrderBy = "Order By User_Name, UserRole_Id`. Basically, you add a second parameter to the Order By clause, telling the sql to sort by two priorities. The syntax might be slightly off, but that should give you the idea.

You might also want to look into Linq or a strongly-typed DataSet, if you're calling SQL Server.

Comment: No I have tried it, it doesnt work.

I want to know how to write the condition to display all the Names of that particular type users.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. To filter the users returned, you'll need to modify the 'where' clause of the sql query: the WhereClause should be something like

where UserRole_name = '<role>'